# ¿Cómo sumar en HTML 5?

Tags: html, html5, html-tabla

Quiero saber si es posible sumar campos de una tabla y mostrarlos en una de sus columnas, les dejo una imagen, para que se entienda.

En la columna total quiero mostrar la suma de los campos cantidad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código en `HTML`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi `JSON`:

```
{
    fecha: new Date('1/4/19'),
    menu1: 'Ajiaco',
    menu2: 'Pollo a la provenzal con papas asadas',
    menu3: 'Lomo de cerdo con arroz',
    menu4: 'Tortilla de acelga con ensaladas',
    menu5: 'Hamburguesa de soya con verduras asadas',
    cant1: 61,
    cant2: 12,
    cant3: 32,
    cant4: 41,
    cant5: 12,
  },
  {
    fecha: new Date('2/4/19'),
    menu1: 'Lentejas a la parmesana con longaniza',
    menu2: 'Goulash de vacuno con arroz exótico',
    menu3: 'Pavo al romero con corbatas atomatadas',
    menu4: 'Omelette a la jardinera con ensaladas',
    menu5: 'Budin tricolor con verduras salteadas',
    cant1: 11,
    cant2: 2,
    cant3: 42,
    cant4: 4,
    cant5: 2,
  },...................................................
```

Espero se pueda hacer sin `JS` ya que mi idea es mostrar el total actual que pusieron y no tener que recargar el `dataSource`.
Saludos! y muchas gracias

Comment: Ya probaste con `{{row.cant1+row.cant2+...}}`

Comment: si funciona :D !, lo unico que estaria quedando seria hacer que se actualiza cuando cambie la cantidad de uno de los campos "cantidad". Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

envuelve las operaciones en llaves, variables dentro.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  {{row.cant1+row.cant2+row.cant3+row.cant4+row.cant5}}
</td>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!, lo unico que me toca ahora es que se actualice apenas cambie un valor de las columnas "cantidad". Saludos y de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: si te sirvió, acepta la respuesta y ciérrala.
 por otra parte, eso que quieres hacer, creo que solo es en codigo JS